# Is it possible to execute immediate like this

Tags: plsql, plsqldeveloper

This code works:

```
uno:=1;
dos :='insert into TRABAJADOR('||inValuesToInsert||') values('||inValuestoPas||')';
execute IMMEDIATE dos using uno,addColN, addColS(8),addColD,addColS(100),
addColS(60),addFKColN('DEPT'),addFKColS('PAIS'),addFKColS('CATEGORIA')  ;
```

But I need to do the execute immediate statement like this (the variable tres contains the data below, sorry for the syntax, I know it's not well done):

```
tres:= 'dos using uno,addColN, addColS(8),addColD,addColS(100),
addColS(60),addFKColN('DEPT'),addFKColS('PAIS'),addFKColS('CATEGORIA')'
uno:=1;
dos :='insert into TRABAJADOR('||inValuesToInsert||') values('||inValuestoPas||')';
execute IMMEDIATE dos using tres;
```

Is this possible? Please give to me another suggestion in case of do not be possible. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to understand the difference between just random part of string of SQL query (for example, `' from table1 t1 join table2 t2 '`) and parameter. Parameter is a certain placeholder, which always means value of something (field, variable, etc.), that will be provided later, in runtime. In `USING` clause of `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` statement you can use only parameters. If you want to construct your query in runtime from parts, you can do it, but you have to process names of fields and parameters by different methods. Example:

```
declare
  field_list varchar2(100) := 'my_field1, my_field2, my_field3';
  table_name varchar2(30) := 'my_table';
  v1 number := 1;
  v2 number := 2;
  v3 number := 3;
begin
  execute immediate 'insert into ' || table_name || '(' || field_list || 
     ') values (:p1, :p2, :p3)' using v1, v2, v3;
end;
/
```

Here `:P1`, `:P2` and `:P3` is parameters, that will be replaced by their values from variables `v1`, `v2` and `v3`. `table_name` and `field_list` from the point of view of a server is NOT parameters, it is static names of database objects.

Comment: i know that part, but supposedly i don't know almost nothing about this table because could be any table, and i need to do this dynamically. that why i can't pass that variables because i don't know how much or the info of any of these columns. if you could tell me another way. thx any way

Comment: @otoniel.cantillo Then you know all what you need. Ii is unclear in your example how you receive names of tables, columns and values to insert, so I can't say anything else.